# Specify a starting point for unix find and replace, then increment

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, perl

I'm doing a renumbering of a reference attribute in an xml file. The attribute is, for example, `data-seq="1"`. I can already renumber that attribute in all files by using this:

```
find $DATA_PATH/content/*.xml -exec perl -pi -e 's/data-seq="[0-9]+(?=")/qq(data-seq=").++$n/ge' {} +
```

This works great. However I'd like to add a starting point. For example, start renumbering at data-seq="125" and then go up from there. Is that possible?

Here is an example of some of the xml (just a small snippet that shows the attribute in question and some other tags):

```
<b>Reconciliation</b>
<p>As often happens, just as one is beginning to find a solution <span class="page" title="20" data-seq="34"/>to a particular problem the problem becomes less pressing or ceases to exist.</p>
<span class="page" title="21" data-seq="35"/>
<b>The Multi-Plant Enterprise</b>
<p>The MNE is...
```

What I would like to do is ignore everything before 125 and start renumbering, at 126, across all files once it finds data-seq="125". This is to fix issues where that attribute, which should be sequential, has gaps or repeats in it which throws off all the other numbers after the gap or repeat.

I don't need to check the structural integrity of the tagging or anything like that, just increment the numbering.

These are all unix text files, by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give an example of your input and desired output. Should the numbers increase only in each file and go back to `125` again for the next one? Should they increase over all files? Should numbers under 125 be left alone? It's very hard to understand what you need without an example.

Comment: With some sample (valid) XML source and desired result, we can almost certainly do what you ask. I would suggest that sequential renumbering needs the whole thing to be done within `perl` rather than feeding if off `find`.

Comment: So to clarify - find `<span>` tags containing `data-seq`. Skip any less than 125. Renumber all above 125 sequentially. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I really don't even need to find the <span> tags since data-seq= is not something that will be in the main data.

Answer (score 2):

Without some XML example, this is hard. I would strongly urge NOT using regular expressions, because regular expressions really don't do XML very well.

I would probably approach it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my $start_renumber = 125;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented_a' ) -> parse ( \*DATA ); 
foreach my $test_elt ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//test[@data-seq]' ) ) {
     $test_elt -> set_att('data-seq', $start_renumber++ );
}
$twig -> print; 

__DATA__
<xml>
   <test data-seq="999" />
   <test some-other="fish" />
   <test data-seq="123125" />
</xml>
```

Turns our output into:

```
<xml>
  <test data-seq="125" />
  <test some-other="fish" />
  <test data-seq="126" />
</xml>
```

And combine it with `File::Find` to do this to all the files you desire.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use File::Find;

my $start_renumber = 125;

sub update_data_seq {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;
    if ( $element -> att('data-seq') > 125 ) { 
        $element->set_att( 'data-seq', $start_renumber++ );
    }
}

sub process_xml {
    next unless -f;
    next unless m/\.xml/;
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
        twig_handlers => { '//span[@data-seq]' => \&update_data_seq }
    );
    $twig->parsefile_inplace($File::Find::name);

}

find( \&process_xml, "/path/to/search/for/xml",
    "/some/other/path/if/you/want" );
```